How can I combine two sheets in a Google Sheet, where each sheet has the same index but different columns, and Sheet B is a subset of Sheet A?
Sheet A has columns like this:



PARID
TAXYR
LIVUNIT
LOCATION_DESC




data
data
data
data



and Sheet B has columns like this:



PARID
ARPLAND
ARPBUILDING
PRILAND




data
data
data
data



PARID is in the index column on the two sheets.
I want to end up with a Sheet B (a subset of the data), that includes all of the columns from Sheet A for corresponding PARID values.  So Sheet B should end up looking like:



PARID
ARPLAND
ARPBUILDING
PRILAND
TAXYR
LIVUNIT
LOCATION_DESC




12345
data
data
data
data
data
data



after pulling the values for PARID of 12345 from Sheet A.
Can someone recommend a way to do this?

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Enter the following formula into the cell of Sheet B where you want to begin loading columns from Sheet A.  Adjust the variables ( $A:$H, COLUMN(B:D) ) to choose the range of columns you want to pull from Sheet A.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, SheetA!$A:$H, COLUMN(B:D), FALSE)))

pseudocode for cell SheetB!E2:
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SheetA!A2:D, {2, 3, 4}, 0)))

